# Terraform and using provisioners

Tags: terraform

I have a module that creates some [VMs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/vmware/vcd/latest/docs/resources/vapp_vm) (along with a VApp) and I need to enable users of that module to pass scripts that would get run on creation and/or deletion of each VM. For example, to enroll the VM into a company authentication system, CMDB, monitoring system or other.
And I just cannot find a way to implement it nicely.

There are several approaches that I've tried:

- Passing a script that gets passed directly to `command`s inside `provisioner` blocks on each VM resource.

  Advantages of this approach:

  - Clean and simple - there are no additional resources.
  - Works as intended - runs on creation and/or deletion.

  The problems with this approach:

  - You can only pass one script per VM.

    You could concatenate them together, but that has obvious drawbacks like the failure in one is then a failure in everything leaving things in an inconsistent state. Retrying gets pretty messy.
  - It's somewhat ugly since if the `command` is null, Terraform crashes.

    As a workaround, you could pass a one-liner containing only a comment about why it's there but that doesn't exactly make it pretty.
- Creating a separate `null_resource` for each VM-script combination and putting the script there.

  Advantages of this approach:

  - There is a separate resource for each script for each VM that if failed could be retried.

  The problems with this approach:

  - Problems arise when updating the scripts.

    Creation script updates can be ignored with a `lifecycle` ignore statement since if you're changing the enroll procedure after a machine has already been succesfully enrolled, you don't need to enroll it again.

    But changing a `when = destroy` script results in the resource being recreated. Meaning it being destroyed and created with the new version of a script. Which in turn triggers the run of the old script which is very unlikely to be desirable.
- Creating "runner" `null_resource`s that only contain the name of a script to run. The script and its content is managed through a set of `local_file` resources.

  Advantages of this approach:

  - Script content is separated from script execution.

  The problems with this approach:

  - This falls apart in ephemeral environments (like running Terraform in a new container each time) where the files would have to be created each time. Maybe this can be worked around though seems it might be difficult because `depends_on` fails if something other than a static resource is used - fails when trying to use resource subscripts.

Additional considerations:

- Using mechanisms of pushing those scripts to VMs and having them run there is undesirable because:

  - Additional risk of having to handle secrets passed to a lot of machines.
  - There is the assumption that the machines can also reach the APIs that is not always true.
- The hack of putting information from other resources in `triggers` (because a `when = destroy` provisioner can only use references to `self`) is a bit worrisome because relying on it means everything will break completely if Terraform developers decide to remove it entirely.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My question is if there is a way to work around all of these problems that I haven't thought of.
Or would I end up having to write my own provider to handle it in the way I want?